# io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException: Signed Claims JWSs are not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I just added Jwt to my application. When I'm trying to send get request via postman which require authorization, then I've got following error:

**io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException: Signed Claims JWSs are not supported.**

I'm sending in body "Authorization" as a Header and "Bearer token-value" as a Value.

Have anyone idea how to solve that?

Here is my jwt class:

```
@Service
public class JwtUtil {

private String SECRET_KEY = "secret";

public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
}

public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
}

public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}

public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJwt(token).getBody();
}

public Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
}

public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
    return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
}

public String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
    return Jwts.builder()
            .setClaims(claims)
            .setSubject(subject)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
}

public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String userName = extractUsername(token);
    return (userName.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}
```

}

and here is my filter:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

    String userName = null;
    String jwt = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        userName = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    }

    if (userName != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.myUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userName);

        if (jwtUtil.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
}
```

EDIT: 
here's stacktrace:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException: Signed Claims JWSs are not supported.
at io.jsonwebtoken.JwtHandlerAdapter.onClaimsJws(JwtHandlerAdapter.java:50) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:487) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJwt(DefaultJwtParser.java:514) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
at com.tradesystem.jwt.JwtUtil.extractAllClaims(JwtUtil.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
at com.tradesystem.jwt.JwtUtil.extractClaim(JwtUtil.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at com.tradesystem.jwt.JwtUtil.extractUsername(JwtUtil.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
at com.tradesystem.jwt.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

---

Comment: Exception is thrown exactly in method extractAllClaims:  return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJwt(token).getBody();

Comment: Shouldnt you use `parseClaimsJws`? Somehting like `Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();`

Comment: That was the mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You should use `parseClaimsJws()` instead of `parseClaimsJwt()` to verify the **JWS** (**JWT with signature**) :

```java
Jwts.parser()
    .setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY)
    .parseClaimsJws(token)
    .getBody();
```

Answer (score 4):

If anyone facing an issue with spring boot 3.0.instead of `parser()` use `parserBuilder()`.

```
Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(JwtSigningKey).build().parse(token).getBody();
```

Hope this will help and upvote for upcoming stackoverflowers.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder()
            .setSigningKey(getSigninKey())
            .build()
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody();
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34678425)

Answer (score 0):

The parseClaimsJwt(token) method works with unsigned JWTS.
The parseClaimsJws(token) method is suitable for JWT with a JWS signature.

Comment: Pardon me, but the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61016123/io-jsonwebtoken-unsupportedjwtexception-signed-claims-jwss-are-not-supported/61017392#61017392) already says the exact, same thing: _You should use parseClaimsJws() instead of parseClaimsJwt() to verify the JWS (JWT with signature)_ Can you explain why you posted an answer which is essentially a repeat of [part of] the accepted answer?